# How to deploy OpenVPN EC2 instance via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set OpenVPN using Terraform but did not find any way to do that. I would like to use terraform to deploy OpenVPN ec2 server. How do I get the OpenVPN AMI id to place on terraform? Or Do I have to deploy a traditional ec2 ubuntu server and install OpenVPN manually?

Comment: you can review the code here https://github.com/DNXLabs/terraform-aws-openvpn for some help. This is not my work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use traditional Ec2 instance and install OpenVPN from user data.

You can look into this [Github repository](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install)

**[Headless install](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install)**

> It's also possible to run the script headless, e.g. without waiting for user input, in an automated manner.

Example usage:

```
AUTO_INSTALL=y ./openvpn-install.sh

# or

export AUTO_INSTALL=y
./openvpn-install.sh
```

When OpenVPN is installed, you can run the script again, and you will get the choice to:

```
Add a client
Remove a client
Uninstall OpenVPN
```

Here is Terraform code that you can try

```
resource "aws_instance" "openvpn" {
  ami                         = "ami-0d2f82a622136a696" //us-west-2
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.vpn.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  subnet_id                   = "${aws_subnet.PubSubnet2a.id}"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.aws-vpn-profile.name}"
  user_data                   = "${data.template_file.vpn.rendered}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env_prefix_name}-vpn"
  }
}

data "template_file" "vpn" {
  template = "${file("bash_scripts/vpnuserdata.sh")}"

  vars = {
    region_name              = "${var.region}"
  }
}
```

vpnuserdata.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
/usr/bin/yum update -y
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angristan/openvpn-install/master/openvpn-install.sh
chmod +x openvpn-install.sh
export AUTO_INSTALL=y
./openvpn-install.sh
```

Comment: Hi. Just quick question. `ami-0d2f82a622136a696` would be for which region?

Comment: Hi, @Marcin this is for us-west-2, which should be base on some variable to make it working with other regions.